# Is having two routePaths for the same target a good idea?

Tags: routes, typo3, tx-news, realurl, typo3-10.x

I'm migrating *realurl* configuration for extension *news* to route enhancers. The *realurl* configuration is a mix of `fixedPostVars` and `postVarSets`. Therefore speaking urls of news single views are build in two different ways:

- https://example.org/my-news-list-page/single-view-page/my-news-title
- https://example.org/my-news-list-page/single-view-page/news/my-news-title (including a `postVarSets` prefix named *news*)

Now with route enhancers I would like to have all links built without the prefix but still be able to resolve links with or without the prefix.

In my route enhancers configuration I added the following two routePaths in this exact order which seems to work just fine:

```
- { routePath: '/news/{news-title}', _controller: 'News::detail', _arguments: {'news-title': 'news'}}
- { routePath: '/{news-title}', _controller: 'News::detail', _arguments: {'news-title': 'news'}}
```

In a reversed order this is not working as links are built with the prefix. I'm wondering if the processing order of routePaths is reliable. Is using routePaths this way a good idea? Or should I better use redirects on webserver level which would be much more work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

If you are not redirecting you should think about duplicate content. I would check if EXT:seo is adding the correct canonical URL (which should be the first matching route) in order to make search engines are happy.

Yet I think this is a bit uncharted territory. Personally I would add a simple generic redirect to your webserver.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful hints about duplicate content and EXT:seo. I think I'll stick to my solution for now as most links are already without prefix. I'll take a close look at statistics once the new configuration is live. If there's more than just a few page calls with the prefix I can still add webserver redirects. Otherwise I'll just remove the routePath with the prefix after a while.

Comment: With a clear canonical tag or redirect you can educate search engines of your preferred URL. Then after some weeks you can check their index and safely delete the old URL.